# android :how to get noticed when the My Location setting location service is enabled or disabled by user

Tags: android, location

I have a Location service that runs in the background as long as the the device is booted. I requested the network and gps provider update by calling LocationManager requestLocationUpdate method, however, when the My Location setting page is changed by enabling or disabling the location service, the onProviderEnabled or on ProviderDisabled are never called. So I want to know how could my background service got notified everytime the user changes the location setting? Can I do it in a receiver mode which caches the broadcast message ?

Comment: "I have a Location service that runs in the background as long as the the device is booted." -- please don't. Please use the `PendingIntent` version of `requestLocationUpdates()`, or poll using `AlarmManager` and my [`LocationPoller`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll), or something like that.

Comment: To be honest, a location service running constantly in the background is never a good idea.  GPS and data are the 2 services that use up the most battery, and leaving these constantly polling will drain the device about 4 or 5 times faster than usual.  You should poll for location updates periodically, if you are going to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement an extended BroadcastReceiver class within your service that listens for the GPS on/off broadcast.  When the GPS is turned on or off though, it doesn't call the onProviderEnabled() method, it calls the GpsStatus.OnGpsStatusChanged() method.

The broadcast sent when the GPS is changed has event values:

GPS_EVENT_STARTED
GPS_EVENT_STOPPED

See the [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Br) API on how to implement a Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: Thanks John for the answer, but the method you mentioned is only for the GPS setting, what if the user enable only the network provider?

Comment: the gps setting change can be detected now, but not the network one.

Comment: To detect when the network provider is enabled or disabled, you'll have to use the ConnectivityManager class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

This will send a broadcast with the String constant ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED when the mobile network is disabled, while the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION constant tells when another network is changed.  You'll have to use the methods in ConnectivityManager to find more detailed information.